# Determine if block has already been registered

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In gutenberg/block-editor, how can I check whether I've already registered a block type? Is there a function I can use? Searching through the Block Editor Handbook I couldn't see a function to check this.

An example of what I am trying to do is below:

```
class My_Block {

    public function __construct() {
        if ( ! SOME_FUNCTION_block_exists('foo/column') ) {
            register_block_type( 'foo/column', my_args );
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: to be fair, [wordpress really wants you to not do this anymore](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/) and instead declare your blocks in `blocks.json`.

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress Gutenberg, using JavaScript you can check if a block exists by name with [getBlockType()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-blocks/#getblocktype), eg:

**JavaScript**

```js
import { getBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

    if (!getBlockType('foo/column')) {
        registerBlockType('foo/column', {
            edit: Edit,
            save,
        });
    }
```

While the above is probably the prefered way, there is a valid case for checking in PHP if a block is already registered, eg. if you want to add a render callback for a block with server side rendering. While I haven't seen a core function for this, I've found a way it can be done by using the REST API [endpoint for block-types](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/block-types/#definition-example-request) to search for the block by `namespace/name`:

**PHP**

```php
class My_Block
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (! is_block_registered('foo/column')) {
            register_block_type('foo/column', $args);
        }
    }

    private function is_block_registered($block_name)
    {
        // Use REST API to query if block exists by <namespace>/<name>
        $route = new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/block-types/' . $block_name);
        $request = rest_do_request($route);

        if ($request->status == 404) {
            // Block is not found/registered
            return false;
        }
        // Block is registered (status is 200)
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the method ´is_registered()´ in the class ´WP_Block_Type_Registry´ (that class handles the registration of blocks). See the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_block_type_registry/is_registered/

```
class My_Block {

    public function __construct() {
        if ( ! WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->is_registered( 'foo/column' ) ) {
            register_block_type( 'foo/column', my_args );
        }
    }

}
```